# tensorflow bijector construction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

I am new to tensorflow distribution and bijector. I know when they design tensorflow distribution package, they partition a tensor's shape into three groups: [sample shape, batch_shape, event_shape]. But I find it hard to understand why when we define a new bijector class, they always defines parent class's event dimension to be 1. For example, the following code is a Real-NVP bijector class, and in its **init** function:

```
super(NVPCoupling, self).__init__(
                event_ndims=1, validate_args=validate_args, name=name)
```

But as I understand it, this real-NVP class is acting on a tensor whose event dimension is D, right?

```
def net(x, out_size):
        return layers.stack(x, layers.fully_connected, [512, 512, out_size])

    # Affine Coupling layer for Real-NVP


    class NVPCoupling(tfb.Bijector):
        """NVP affine coupling layer for 2D units.
        """

        def __init__(self, D, d, layer_id=0, validate_args=False, name="NVPCoupling"):
            """
            Args:
              d: First d units are pass-thru units.
            """
            # first d numbers decide scaling/shift factor for remaining D-d numbers.
            super(NVPCoupling, self).__init__(
                event_ndims=1, validate_args=validate_args, name=name)
            self.D, self.d = D, d
            self.id = layer_id
            # create variables here
            tmp = tf.placeholder(dtype=DTYPE, shape=[1, self.d])
            self.s(tmp)
            self.t(tmp)

        def s(self, xd):
            with tf.variable_scope('s%d' % self.id, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                return net(xd, self.D - self.d)

        def t(self, xd):
            with tf.variable_scope('t%d' % self.id, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                return net(xd, self.D - self.d)

        def _forward(self, x):
            xd, xD = x[:, :self.d], x[:, self.d:]
            yD = xD * tf.exp(self.s(xd)) + self.t(xd)  # [batch, D-d]
            return tf.concat([xd, yD], axis=1)

        def _inverse(self, y):
            yd, yD = y[:, :self.d], y[:, self.d:]
            xD = (yD - self.t(yd)) * tf.exp(-self.s(yd))
            return tf.concat([yd, xD], axis=1)

        def _forward_log_det_jacobian(self, x):
            event_dims = self._event_dims_tensor(x)
            xd = x[:, :self.d]
            return tf.reduce_sum(self.s(xd), axis=event_dims)
```

Also, when we use a sample tensor to train it, the tensor has shape [batch_size, D]. But the tmp placeholder has a shape=[1, self.d] not [Batch_size, self.d]. What is the reason for that. 
Hope some experts could clarify this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event_ndims` is the *number* of event dimensions, not the size of the input. Thus `event_ndims=1` operates on vectors, `event_ndims=2` on matrices, and so on. See the `__init__` docstring for the `Bijector` class.